# Comparing casted/converted/str_to_date values in CASE?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm hurting for an answer on this one. I'm not great at SQL just yet, but I'm trying to write a select statement that finds dates within a certain range. My problem, I think, is that the date values are strings and it doesn't compare properly. This is the code I've got so far.

```
SELECT CONCAT (suffix, " ", lname, " ", fname, " ", name) AS "Name",
    id AS "Member ID",
    CONCAT (address1, " ", address2, " ") AS "Address Line 1", 
    CONCAT (city, " ", state, " - ", zip)  AS "Address Line 2", 
        CASE
            WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires,'%d.%m.%Y') > 01/01/2023 THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END AS "Subscriber?"
FROM roster
LIMIT 100000
```

I've tried casting, converting, and the str_to_date function - /'s, .'s, you name it. All 1090 results are No. These should definitely at least have a couple yeses. This is for MySQL, by the by.

Answer (score 2):

You should never store date or time information as strings. Ideally you would take the time to correct this so that all your queries will be simpler in future.

However to address the immediate issue please get used to concept of "**date literal**" which is how we give a SQL query a date and use a ISO 8601 compatible format for these literals i.e. '2023-01-01' - and precede this with the word "date":

So, your comparison needs a valid "**date literal**" e.g.

```
STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires,'%d.%m.%Y') > DATE '2023-01-01'
```

Notice that to convert your strings into date, you should use the format of how those strings have been stored. e.g. if your data looks like this:

```
23.12.2022
13.04.2022
```

Then `STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires,'%d.%m.%Y')` results in a date, and that date can then be compared to a valid "date literal". However if your data contains just 2 digit years or delimiters other than periods and/or they are in dmy or mdy sequence then you need a different str_to_date for each format your data holds. Plus strings can be invalid dates or even nothing like a date at all. This is why storing dates as strings is a bad idea.

i.e. `STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires,'%d.%m.%Y')` will work for strings like `23.12.2022` but it will return `NULL` if the strings are `23,12,23` or `2022-12-23` or lots of other possible date format variants.

---

Further information aimed at changing that string column into a date column:

```
CREATE TABLE roster (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  regionexpires VARCHAR(20)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO roster (id, name, regionexpires)
VALUES
  (1, 'John Doe', '2022-12-31'),
  (2, 'Jane Smith', '31.12.2022'),
  (3, 'Bob Johnson', '2022.12.31'),
  (4, 'Alice Lee', '31-12-2022'),
  (5, 'Tom Brown', '2022/12/31'),
  (6, 'Sara Green', '12/31/2022'),
  (7, 'Mike Davis', '2022-31-12'),
  (8, 'Emily White', '31-2022-12'),
  (9, 'Mark Black', '2022-12-32'),
  (10, 'Lisa Grey', '2022-13-31');
```

> ```
> Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
-- DDL to alter the "roster" table with a date column "expiry_date"
ALTER TABLE roster ADD COLUMN expiry_date DATE;
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
-- Temporarily disable strict mode for the current session
SET sql_mode = '';
```

```
UPDATE roster 
SET expiry_date = CASE 
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y.%m.%d') IS NOT NULL THEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y.%m.%d')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NOT NULL THEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y-%m-%d')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y/%m/%d') IS NOT NULL THEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y/%m/%d')
    
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d.%m.%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d.%m.%Y')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d-%m-%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d-%m-%Y')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d/%m/%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d/%m/%Y')
    
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m.%d.%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m.%d.%Y')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m-%d-%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m-%d-%Y')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m/%d/%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m/%d/%Y')
    ELSE NULL
END
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 10  Changed: 6  Warnings: 52
> ```

```
-- Re-enable strict mode if desired
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

```
-- Sample query to retrieve data from the "roster" table with formatted dates
SELECT id, name, expiry_date,regionexpires,
  CASE 
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y.%m.%d') IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y.%m.%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y/%m/%d') IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%Y/%m/%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d.%m.%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d.%m.%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d-%m-%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d/%m/%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m.%d.%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m.%d.%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m-%d-%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m/%d/%Y') IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    ELSE 'Invalid date'
  END AS regionexpires_formatted
FROM roster;
```

| id | name | expiry_date | regionexpires | regionexpires_formatted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 2022-12-31 | 2022-12-31 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2 | Jane Smith | 2031-12-20 | 31.12.2022 | 2031-12-20 |
| 3 | Bob Johnson | 2022-12-31 | 2022.12.31 | 2022-12-31 |
| 4 | Alice Lee | 2031-12-20 | 31-12-2022 | 2031-12-20 |
| 5 | Tom Brown | 2022-12-31 | 2022/12/31 | 2022-12-31 |
| 6 | Sara Green | 2022-12-31 | 12/31/2022 | 2022-12-31 |
| 7 | Mike Davis | *null* | 2022-31-12 | Invalid date |
| 8 | Emily White | *null* | 31-2022-12 | Invalid date |
| 9 | Mark Black | *null* | 2022-12-32 | Invalid date |
| 10 | Lisa Grey | *null* | 2022-13-31 | Invalid date |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w2WFFiof)

Comment: I'd like to add that while MySQL allows `'2023-01-01'` as a date literal, in standard SQL you'd have to precede it with the word DATE: `DATE '2023-01-01'`. I suggest to do so in MySQL, too.

Comment: Thanks for this, good advice. Have to admit it is one of those items I tend to overlook. Adopted into the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, date's get formatted like strings in MySQL.  So something like  `WHEN STR_TO_DATE(regionexpires,'%d-%m-%Y') > '01-01-2023 THEN 'Yes'`  Notice the use of dashes in both the formatting string and the date value itself. Slashes might work, don't have an instance in front of me that I can tests with though.

Comment: No. This will result in "Incorrect DATE value: '01-01-2023'", because with a date on the left-hand side of the comparison, MySQL wants a date on the right-hand side, too. `'01-01-2023'` is not a valid date literal. `DATE '2023-01-01'` is.

Comment: Thanks for the that. I was going off of a memory from way too long ago.